# Getting wrong Location lat/long

Tags: android, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

I'm using Nexus 6p with Android 7.1.2. I set the device location accuracy to be `HIGH_ACCURACY`. 
In my code, I have a background service for location update, using the `FusedLocation` API. As you can see I also set the location request priority to be `HIGH_ACCURACY`.
Now I've tested it when the device was on my desk without any movements and for most of the time I've got the same LAT/LONG values and sometimes I saw a minor change with the LAT/LONG values even though the device wasn't moving.
So I printed the Location accuracy using the `getAccuracy` method. 
The docs says that if `getAccuracy` method returns a value >= 68 so it means that there is a high chance that the device (user) is at this location.
So I tried to use this method (another version of the code below) and checked if getAccuracy returns a value >= 68 and then print the location details.
Guess what? it didn't help so much..

The next thing I tried is to rotate the device and I saw that when the device was in landsacpe mode with the back to me, the location lat/long was changed (even though i didn't go anywhere) and the accuracy was increased and in some cases reached to the value of 180.

So I don't understand this:

Why sometimes the device's lat/long values are different even though the device is lying on the desk and doesn't move?

And how the rotations is impact on the location accuracy?!

**My Code:**

```
 public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private boolean playsServiceAvailable;

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate();

        initRequestLocation();

        playsServiceAvailable = checkPlayServicesConnection();

        setupLocationApiClient();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);

        if (!playsServiceAvailable || googleApiClient.isConnected())            
        {

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        setupLocationApiClient();

        if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: googleApiclient.connect()");
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

        if (this.playsServiceAvailable && this.googleApiClient != null)
        {
            this.googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
            this.googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
            this.googleApiClient.disconnect();
            this.googleApiClient = null;
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(this.googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
        googleApiClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:\n\t\t\t" +
                "CurrentLocation:\n\t\t\t\t" +
                "ACCURACY: " + currentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n\t\t\t\t" +
                "LAT: " + currentLocation.getLatitude() + "\n\t\t\t\t" +
                "LONG: " + currentLocation.getLongitude() + "\n\t\t\t\t" +
                "TIME: " + currentLocation.getTime());

    }

    private boolean checkPlayServicesConnection ()
    {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initRequestLocation()
    {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(1000);
    }

    private void setupLocationApiClient()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"setupLocationApiClient");
        if (googleApiClient == null)
            initGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private synchronized void initGoogleApiClient()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"initGoogleApiClient");
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is GPS In-accuracy this not issue with device. It try to fetch exact location so that's why it move here and there try to improve gps accuracy. Try to set smallest displacement and interval for more accurate result.

```
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
 mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(27);//27 meter
 mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); // Update location every 5 seconds
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 
 mLocationRequest, this);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Ok.. it seems to work.. 
So if I get it right.. the setSmallestDisplacement will cause the location to update only if there is a difference of 27 meters (in your example)

Comment: Yes I am using this in my app and its give me very accurate result.